# Access Denied (HRESULT 0x80070005) in new ControlChannelTrigger (WinRT)

Tags: c#, background, windows-runtime

I an in complete despair...

Here's my code:

```
ControlChannelTrigger theChannel = new ControlChannelTrigger("channelId", 15, ControlChannelTriggerResourceType.RequestHardwareSlot);
```

which always throws an UnauthorizedAccessException (HRESULT 0x80070005).

Here's a manifest I use

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
  <Identity Name="cf45d5c8-2936-4d1f-9075-51a87ceb60ba" Publisher="CN=snuk182" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Applic</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>snuk182</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion>6.2.0</OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested>6.2.0</OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="Applic.App">
      <VisualElements DisplayName="Applic" Logo="Assets\Logo.png" SmallLogo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="Applic" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646" ToastCapable="true">
        <LockScreen Notification="badgeAndTileText" BadgeLogo="ImageResources\badge.png" />
        <DefaultTile ShowName="allLogos" WideLogo="ImageResources\widelogo.png" />
        <SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="Applic.BackgroundTask">
          <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="controlChannel" />
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="removableStorage" />
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Have not found any answer either here or in web. Have no idea what's going on...

Comment: Have you tried adding the local network capability?

Comment: Tried the next changes with no success:  
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="removableStorage" />
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />

Have not found any "local" network cap.

Answer (score 1):

Haha, I've sorted it out. It was too obvious to do it before the weekend.
**I had to mark my application as Lock Screen app in System Settings.**
Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Originally i couldnt figure out how to "mark my application as Lock Screen app in System Settings" but found it here and wanted to share
[image]