# IBackgroundTask with ControlChannelTrigger, project manifest errors

Tags: c#, desktop, windows-10-universal

I have a separate component project (BackgroundWorkers) within my solution that encapsulates my `IBackgroundTask`.  My main ui project (SufaceHubMonitoring) has a reference to it and is also its own separate project within the solution.
[image]

Since my Im going to be using these background task I need to declare them in my manifest
[image]
but as you can see in the image there is an error because neither Executable nor Start page is populated.
However I get neither when building my component (BackgroundWorkers) project.  The only thing it outputs is

> C:\SurfaceHubMonitoring\trunk\BackgroundWorker\bin\x86\Debug\BackgroundWorkers.winmd

How should my background task be declared in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error went away after I put

```
$targetnametoken$.exe
```

in the Executable field

NOTE:
also had an access error, which was resolved via this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580643/access-denied-hresult-0x80070005-in-new-controlchanneltrigger-winrt/37052172#37052172)